# Heroku releases clear history

Tags: heroku

Heroku makes release of each deployed app stage. Can I backward to some release and clear all releases ahead it? Something equivalent to git `git reset --hard 'specific commit(realise)'`.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku works like any other git server in this regard.  Generally, anything you could do on github, you can do on Heroku.  Obviously within reason, given what Heroku's main intent is.

what you probably want to do is make sure your local repo is the way you want it to be, and then:

`git push --force heroku HEAD:master`

Additionally, the heroku app has a releases command:

```
Usage: heroku releases

 list releases

Example:

 $ heroku releases
 === example Releases
 v1 Config add FOO_BAR by email@example.com 0s ago
 v2 Config add BAR_BAZ by email@example.com 0s ago
 v3 Config add BAZ_QUX by email@example.com 0s ago

Additional commands, type "heroku help COMMAND" for more details:

  releases:info RELEASE        #  view detailed information for a release
  releases:rollback [RELEASE]  #  roll back to an older release
```

Comment: You right but not at all. Look c1, c2, c3 (c is named commit) and I deploy each ( push c1, c2, and c3). Then `git reset --hard 'c2'` and `git push -f heroku master`. And make heroku releases it's return r1(c1), r2(c2), r3(c3), r4(c2). I want make it's look to r1(c1), r2(c2), r4(c2) or r1(c1), r2(c2). The main target is clear my code from server if client not pay. Anyway thank you for answer.

Comment: If your client doesn't pay, you can just disable the app or push another version with the code removed, no?

Comment: I'm not owner of application. I'm collaborator.

Comment: okay, but still, my point is that if you have the ability to rollback a release, you also have the ability to remove critical components from your codebase and push those changes out.  I think you're trying to make this more complicated than it needs to be. :)

Comment: better yet, build a `kill switch` into your app, so all you need to do is set a flag to disable functionality.  That way you're simply giving your client incentive to pay up.